# Should the JVM be restated on StackOverflowError?

Tags: error-handling, jvm, stack-overflow

What damage could a **StackOverflowError** cause? 
Should the JVM be restarted after a **StackOverflowError**?

Answer (score 1):

Since SOE is an asynchronously thrown Error (OOMEs are another example) that can be thrown in the middle of any code block it might leave objects in an inconsistent state. This is especially visible with lock abstractions - including lock classes in the standard library - that might be left in some unexpected state (e.g. permanently locked without owner).

It does not corrupt internal JVM state, so the VM itself can be considered functional after an OOM, but application- and library-level state should be considered inconsistent unless the code in question has been very carefully designed to be resistant to async exceptions.

So yes, unless specifically designed to deal with the situation it is usually better to restart after encountering a SOE.